# javascript php code to echo selected data inside multiple textbox

Tags: javascript, php

My form has listbox ok

I am selecting data on change event of listbox using some javascript

```
<script>
function showUser(str) {

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
             document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getdata.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();

}
</script>


<select class="special-flexselect" name="society" onChange="showUser(this.value)">                                      
    <option  value="" ></option>
    <?php foreach ($society as $soc){ ?>    
<option  value="<?php echo $soc["society"]; ?>"><?php echo $soc["society"]; ?></option>
    <?php }?>
    </select>

    **Data displays in below div**              

<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>
```

**But i need to echo data inside multiple textboxes..so what to change in javascript and how to echo data inside all textboxes here..**

plz help me...

**below is my 3 textboxes in which i need to echo  data**

```
<input type="text"   name="amount" />
<input type="text"   name="coupon" />
<input type="text"   name="city" />
```

php code

```
<?php
$q = $_GET['q'];

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','circulation_scheme_prepaid');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
$sql="SELECT * FROM societymaster WHERE society = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo $row['city'] ;
 echo $row['amount'] ;
 echo $row['coupon'] ;


}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: So one single textbox (`#txtHint` in this case) is working?

Comment: no if i put this div <div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>  then works but when i put textbox and place same id in textbox then not working...

Comment: Ah, you have to use `xy.value` instead of `xy.innerHTML` when using an `<input />`

Comment: and for multiple textbox....how to call id of each textbox and echo data inside this..

Comment: I guess `$row['city']` should be displayed in the input named `city`? Can multiple rows be returned from your database call or just one?